# JSON Enum conversion for javascript null property

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization, json.net

i searched on SO and Google for hours but cannot find an answer to my question. I'm in the middle of a migration from .NET framework to dotnetcore 6 and i am struggling in the JSON options i can set at Startup.cs.

Using the AddNewtonsoftJson extension, it seems that when a POST is done from javascript, where properties of an object that should map to an Enum are passed as null, resulting in the value that cannot be converted towards Enum (non-nullable). Which seems right, they are non-nullable and in fact, they should not have been passed as 'null' from javascript.

However, this worked in .NET Framework where we used a JsonMediaTypeFormatter for this. It seemed some hidden magic happened that mapped a null property was converted to a default value of the specific Enum datatype of the property. It is unclear how that even worked or could happen but this is how our legacy client-side code relies on it.

So i want to achieve the same thing. Probably writing a custom Json Converter that checks for a null property where the mapped type is of type Enum. I would then want to assign the object property as the default (first value?) value of the corresponding value.

Note: i cannot inherit from StringEnumConverter, as our Enums are effectively ints when passed.

Anyone has some idea how i could achieve this?

I have currently following but this does not do what i want:

```
.AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
            {
                jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
            {
                opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                opts.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve my requirements this way, through writing a custom converter:

- When writing, the int value will be written as json
- When reading an incoming json, the enum value will be set or when null, the defaultEnum type value will be set.

public namespace test {

```
public class EnumNullValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (int)value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
        {
            return GetDefaultValue(objectType);
        }

        var intValue = serializer.Deserialize<int>(reader);
        return Enum.Parse(objectType, intValue.ToString());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsEnum;
    }

    private object GetDefaultValue(Type enumType)
    {
        var attribute = enumType.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>(inherit: false);
        if (attribute != null)
            return attribute.Value;

        var innerType = enumType.GetEnumUnderlyingType();
        var zero = Activator.CreateInstance(innerType);
        if (enumType.IsEnumDefined(## Heading ##zero))
            return zero;

        var values = enumType.GetEnumValues();
        return values.GetValue(0);
    }
```

}